# Using QuantMod/tseries monthlyReturn with dividend

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

Is there are way using Monthly Return function to factor in dividends into the monthlyReturn?

I have my an xts object with price and dividend columns.

Comment: Add the price and dividend columns together and run `monthlyReturn` on that.

Comment: @GSee, I have not thought about it that way. It might present an issue when calculating the return if the dividends happen in the middle of the month.

Comment: Oh. I think I see what you're saying.  You should add the `cumsum` of dividends to the price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TTR::adjRatios` directly to calculate the adjustment ratios necessary to create a "total-return" price series.  Then you can calculate the monthly return using the adjusted series.  Note that you might also need to adjust for splits.

```
library(quantmod)
# create sample data
SPY.Close <- Cl(getSymbols("SPY", auto.assign=FALSE))
SPY.Div <- getDividends("SPY", auto.assign=FALSE)
SPY <- merge(SPY.Close, SPY.Div)
# now adjust close for dividends
ratios <- adjRatios(dividends=SPY[,"SPY.Div"], close=SPY[,"SPY.Close"])
SPY$SPY.Adjusted <- (ratios$Split * ratios$Div) * SPY$SPY.Close
# only keep dates from the original object
SPY <- SPY[index(SPY.Close),]
# calculate returns on raw prices and adjusted prices
ret <- merge(monthlyReturn(Cl(SPY)), monthlyReturn(Ad(SPY)))
```

Comment: this assumes re-investment of dividends, which may or may not be desirable